# Google C++ Style Guide. Why input-then-output parameter ordering?

Tags: c++

In [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Function_Parameter_Ordering), it said:

> When defining a function, parameter order is: inputs, then outputs.

Basically Google suggest function parameter ordering like:

```
void foo(const Foo& input1, const Foo& input2, Foo* output);
```

However, my colleague suggested that the output should be put in the first position. because in this way, foo could accept default values and most of the time output would not use a default value. for example:

```
void foo(Foo* output, const Foo& input1, const Foo& input2 = default);
```

I think what he said make sense. Or is there something we are missing here from aspects of readability, performance, ...? Why the style guide suggest output should be the last?

Comment: I don't think there is any performance advantage for either. It is mainly a matter of taste. No matter what you choose just be consistent it is usage. I think that is precisely the reason it is mentioned in the guidelines, consistency.

Comment: I guess it is a uniform code style, both of them is available, and you can choose the style which is better for your requirement

Comment: Another thought in Google's instance 'might' be compiler optimizations; i.e. if having it their way with certain compiler optimizations makes for a certain type of binary they wish to achieve, it might make since to 'make it a standard' .. thought I'd lean towards it being style over functionality

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why this isn't a problem for the Google style guide is because default arguments are disallowed:

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Default_Arguments

> We do not allow default function parameters, except in limited situations as explained below. Simulate them with function overloading instead, if appropriate.
>
> ## Pros
>
> Often you have a function that uses default values, but occasionally you want to override the defaults. Default parameters allow an easy way to do this without having to define many functions for the rare exceptions. Compared to overloading the function, default arguments have a cleaner syntax, with less boilerplate and a clearer distinction between 'required' and 'optional' arguments.
>
> ## Cons
>
> Function pointers are confusing in the presence of default arguments, since the function signature often doesn't match the call signature. Adding a default argument to an existing function changes its type, which can cause problems with code taking its address. Adding function overloads avoids these problems. In addition, default parameters may result in bulkier code since they are replicated at every call-site -- as opposed to overloaded functions, where "the default" appears only in the function definition.
>
> ## Decision
>
> While the cons above are not that onerous, they still outweigh the (small) benefits of default arguments over function overloading. So except as described below, we require all arguments to be explicitly specified.
>
> One specific exception is when the function is a static function (or in an unnamed namespace) in a .cc file. In this case, the cons don't apply since the function's use is so localized.
>
> In addition, default function parameters are allowed in constructors. Most of the cons listed above don't apply to constructors because it's impossible to take their address.
>
> Another specific exception is when default arguments are used to simulate variable-length argument lists.

```
// Support up to 4 params by using a default empty AlphaNum.
string StrCat(const AlphaNum &a,
              const AlphaNum &b = gEmptyAlphaNum,
              const AlphaNum &c = gEmptyAlphaNum,
              const AlphaNum &d = gEmptyAlphaNum);
```